# Deprecating an old module name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How would I best go about renaming a Ruby Module in a backwards compatible manner?  I have ActiveSupport, so can call deprecation warnings this way, but in this case I'm deprecating the old module name and not the method names.

Example follows:

```
module OldName
  def self.method1
    ...
  end
end
```

Will become:

```
module NewName
  def self.method1
    ...
  end
end
```

I want to generate warnings directing the developer to using `NewName::method1` rather than `OldName::method1`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Often `git grep` works wonders. You can also mass-replace one with the other.

Comment: @tadman Let me clarify, I know how to replace the module names, but I'm looking for advice on how best to warn other users of a gem that the old module name has changed.

Comment: If this is a public gem *and* it depends on ActiveSupport, then the deprecation model is probably the way to go. Sometimes if you're doing a really aggressive overhaul and you're using semantic versioning you should just do a clean break.

Comment: It is, hence why deprecation is desired in this instance.  Struggling to make this work - any code examples that you could point me towards, please?

Comment: As it stands, you are asking for a pure-Ruby solution (@engineersmnky's and mine, for example), which is fine, but if you wish to admit solutions that employ `ActiveSupport` you need to include a Rails tag. Note `Name::meth` references a module method (`meth`) whereas `Name#meth` references an instance method. You need to use the latter to be consistent with your example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for spotting the typo.  See my new response to matthewd's answer.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveSupport provides two ways of deprecating a constant: [DeprecatedConstantAccessor](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Deprecation/DeprecatedConstantAccessor.html) and [DeprecatedConstantProxy](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Deprecation/DeprecatedConstantProxy.html). They each have trade-offs and limitations in when they show the warning (Accessor is when it's accessed; Proxy is when its methods are called) and how they generally behave. You'll probably want to try both to see which one feels right for your use case.

Comment: Thanks, but any code examples I could steal a look at, please?  Not finding this one easy to work out.

Comment: Ok, turns out the difficulty is in the gem itself, not in the deprecation process.  See my new answer below for code example.

Answer (score 2):

Rails 4.1.8 Ruby 2.2.0p0

```
module Fred
  extend self
  def aaa; end
  def bbb; end
  def ccc; end
  def ddd; end
  def eee; end
end

module Bar
  extend self
  def ccc; end
end


ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(Fred, :aaa, bbb: :zzz, ccc: 'use Bar#ccc instead')


Fred.aaa
DEPRECATION WARNING: aaa is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 4.2. (called from __pry__ at (pry):15)
=> nil
```

Same code tried in rails 5.2.0 but no **DEPRECATION WARNING**.

Rails 5.2.0 Ruby 2.5.1p57

```
class Fred
 def aaa; end
 def bbb; end
 def ccc; end
 def ddd; end
 def eee; end
end

class Bar
 def ccc; end
end

ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(Fred, :aaa, bbb: :zzz, ccc: 'use Bar#ccc instead')

> Fred.new.aaa
DEPRECATION WARNING: aaa is deprecated and will be removed from Rails 6.0 (called from irb_binding at (irb):13)
 => nil
```

Comment: Thanks but this seems a sledgehammer to crack a nut - anything more elegant that you could suggest, please?

Comment: Incidentally, isn't it bad form to copy and paste another person's code without crediting them? https://gist.github.com/rafaelfranca/5492531

Comment: @Kitebuggy check now I referred http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Deprecation/MethodWrapper.html
 and made an example

Comment: As a note `Fred.new` and `Bar.new` are not valid. A Module does not allow for instantiation the class  `Module` can be instantiated but a `Module` cannot

Comment: @engineersmnky changed.

Answer (score 1):

You could go with something like:

```
module Bar
  def self.aaa
    'Bar::aaa'
  end

  def baz
    'Bar#baz'
  end
end 

module Foo
  {included: :include,extended: :extend,prepended: :prepend}.each do |mod_method, called_method| 
    singleton_class.define_method(mod_method) do |base|
      warn "Foo is deprecated please use Bar instead"
      base.send(called_method,Bar) 
    end
  end
  def self.method_missing(meth,*args,&block)
    warn "Foo is deprecated please use Bar instead"
    Bar.respond_to?(meth) ? Bar.send(meth,*args,&block) : super
  end
end

class A 
  include Foo # this will throw a warning
end
```

Then

```
Foo.aaa
# Foo is deprecated please use Bar instead
#=> 'Bar::aaa'

A.new.baz  
#=> 'Bar#baz'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
module OldName
  def instance_method(*args)
    yield(args)
  end

  instance_methods.each do |im|
    alias_name = "_#{im.to_s}"
    alias_method alias_name, im
    define_method(im) do |*args, &block|
      warn "Foo is deprecated please use Bar instead"
      public_send(alias_name, *args, &block)
    end
  end
end

class C
  include OldName
end

C.instance_methods && [:im, :_im]
  #=> [:im, :_im]

c = C.new
c._instance_method(2,3) { |a,b| a+b }
  #=> 5
c.instance_method(2,3) { |a,b| a+b }
  # Foo is deprecated please use Bar instead
  #=> 5
```

Alternatively, `public_send(alias_name, *args, &block)` can be replaced with `method(alias_name).call(*args, &block)`.

Comment: @praaveen, no harm, no foul, but by clicking on "edited" I see no bread crumbs left by your misadventure.

Answer (score 0):

I was sideswiped by a bug in the gem I was patching, which caused a few false starts, but the final answer is extremely simple and I include the working code as an example for others:

```
require 'active_support'

OldName = ActiveSupport::Deprecation::DeprecatedConstantProxy.new('OldName', 'NewName')

module NewName
  def self.method1
    puts 'Hello World!'
  end
end


NewName.method1
  #=> Hello World!

OldName.method1
  #=> DEPRECATION WARNING: OldName is deprecated! Use NewName instead. (called from ..)
  #=> Hello World!
```

Simples!

My thanks to @matthewd for re-pointing me in the right direction.