# DEPRECATION WARNING does not show for module in rails 5.2 but works with class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, deprecation-warning, ruby-on-rails-5.2

While I was answering for this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51067686/deprecating-an-old-module-name-in-ruby/51068496#51068496) question found

Rails 4.1.8 Ruby 2.2.0p0

```
module Fred
  extend self
  def aaa; end
  def bbb; end
  def ccc; end
  def ddd; end
  def eee; end
end

module Bar
  extend self
  def ccc; end
end

ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(
  Fred, :aaa, bbb: :zzz, ccc: 'use Bar#ccc instead'
)

Fred.aaa

DEPRECATION WARNING: aaa is deprecated and will be removed
  from Rails 4.2. (called from \__pry__ at (pry):15)
#=> nil
```

**Same code tried in rails 5.2.0 but no DEPRECATION WARNING.**

So what i'm missing here, DEPRECATION WARNING has new update with rails 5.2.0 and will not warn for module?

Comment: Created an issue at github https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/33253 For more infomation.

Comment: This is fix in this pull request https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33325

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>FYI: Rails is open source, the code is publicly available here: https://github.com/rails/rails</sub>

---

Rails5 is using [`Module#prepend`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/deprecation/method_wrappers.rb#L57).

Rails4 is using [`alias_method_chain`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.2.10/activesupport/lib/active_support/deprecation/method_wrappers.rb).

Obviously, [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend) won’t work with module functions. You might do something like:

```
ActiveSupport::Deprecation.deprecate_methods(
  Fred.singleton_class, :aaa
)
```

I did not test the code, but it should work. Also, I would consider this being a bug in Rails5.